# Automount with fstab and systemd

Tags: systemd, fstab, automounting

I added an automount rule to /etc/fstab for a USB drive in my board as follows:

```
/dev/sda1  /media  vfat  noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=2,x-systemd.device-timeout=2 ..
```

I use the device name because it'll be the same, UUID might vary.

After running

```bsh
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart local-fs.target
```

the automount works fine and the drive is mounted in the right path.

However when I check the content of `/proc/mounts`, I see an entry that corresponds to my automount rule but the device name is replaced by **systemd-1**, here:

```
systemd-1 /media autofs rw,relatime,fd=32,pgrp=1,timeout=2,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct 0 0
```

My questions are:

1. Why /dev/sda1 is replaced by *systemd-1*?
2. How to fix it so the device name appears instead?

Comment: For others coming here attempting to get a network filesystem such as cifs configured for automount, use `systemctl restart remote-fs.target` (as opposed to `local-fs.target`)

Answer (score 0):

`autofs` is not your mount point, it's a virtual mount point which systemd uses to monitor access to it, and decide when to mount the actual filesystem. If you try to `cd /media`, you should notice a slight delay, and a new child mountpoint with the actual device.

The advantage of `automount` is the ability to give a reserved mount point to removable devices, without needing to connect them when the system starts.